# After magento verison upgrade from 1.5 to 1.9.2.3 re-indexing and caching not working

Tags: magento, caching, reindex

Last day I upgraded my magneto site from 1.5 to 1.9.2.3. But after that Re-indexing and flush magento cache is not working.
On Re-indexing it throws error 'Cannot initialize the indexer process.' and when try to flush magento cache logout action is working.

I had truncated catalog_product_index_price tables and executed repair query for my db. But no use.

Please suggest me a solution for these two issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's memory issue or `catalog_product_flat_1` or `catalog_product_flat_2` database table issue. Please check [this link](https://techbandhu.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/magento-reindexing-problem/)